# Matplotlib.pylot says 'requirement already satisfied' but also 'Module not found'

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, module

This is a similar question to what I've asked before, but I don't understand what is happening. I am using `pip 20.2.3` and `python 3.8.2` on Windows.

Before, when I typed `pip install matplotlib` or `pip3 install matplotlib` into cmd, I would get a message saying that all the "requirements are satisfied". But when I run `import matplotlib.pylot as plt` on VSCode, it tells me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sound/Desktop/now/Trade Simulation/#2/Trade Simulation.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pylot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pylot'
```

Not only that, I recently just updated pip from `20.2.3` to `20.2.4`. When I run the same command `pip install matplotlib`, instead of saying "requirements are satisfied" like before, I get a massive error message in red that looks like:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\sound\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sound\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9w_lvhnf\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sound\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9w_lvhnf\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\sound\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ihoi_gsj'
         cwd: C:\Users\sound\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9w_lvhnf\matplotlib\
    Complete output (249 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\sound\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\sound\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\sound\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpsqdka5ne'
```

The change in output when I updated pip kind of threw me off. I'm not sure what to do or how to fix this installation error. Any insight would be appreciated.

Using `pip3.8 install -U matplotlib` gives me back

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\12132\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\~atplotlib\\ft2font.cp38-win32.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: Your error indicates a typo: `import matplotlib.pylot as plt` should be `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error indicates a typo, there is no module `pylot` in matplotlib.

The import you have:

`import matplotlib.pylot as plt`

should be:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Wow I really spent all that time for something so small. Thank you! I wouldn't have figured it out myself

Comment: Glad to help. Can't tell you how many times a typo has dragged me down a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple python installations, the use the pipVersion.exe (like pip3.7.exe) for installing `matplotlib`. And one more thing in linux, add the full path to the interpreter in shebang.

Comment: I apologize but I don't quite understand what you're saying

Comment: For each python installation, you will get a pip.exe appended the Version name like pip3.8.exe in the Scripts folder. Use that to install

Comment: If I updated python, would it still append pip?

Comment: Use `pip3.8 install -U matplotlib` is better

Comment: I edited my post as I got another error. This one is new though

Comment: Run as Administrator... right click cmd.exe and choose Run as Administrator

Comment: Now it once again tells me that requirements are all satisfied but I get "Module not found" when I run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` :(

Comment: @WasifHasan They could also use `python -m pip`, it might be simpler.